# Clarification on Akaike's IC (AIC) and BIC for Expectation Maximization with time-changing parameters

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, kalman-filter, bic, information-criteria

I apologize in advance for the trivial question, but I need a clarification on the following issue. Suppose I have a generic model in state-space form described as

$$x_{t+1}=\phi_{t} x_{t}+w_{t+1}$$
$$y_{t}=H_{t}x_{t}+v_{t}$$

Notice that all the parameters in $\phi_{t}, H_{t}$ as well as in $Var(w_{t+1})$ and $Var(v_{t})$ are allowed to be time-varying. Suppose that total number of parameters for each period of interest is indicated by k. Therefore, in the theoretical case where I want to run the Expectation Maximization algorithm to estimate all the model parameters, then the total number of parameters to be estimated is $K=T*k$. Applying the definition of AIC and BIC, we get

$$AIC=-2Loglik+2K=-2Loglik+2T*k$$
$$BIC=-2Loglik+ln(T)2K=-2Loglik+ln(T)2T*k$$

**The problem is that, sometimes, I see general formulations of AIC and BIC where the total number of parameters K is divided by T**. Therefore in this case, one should have:

$$AIC=-2Loglik+2K/T=-2Loglik+2T*k/T$$
$$BIC=-2Loglik+ln(T)2K/T=-2Loglik+ln(T)2T*k/T$$

My questions are:

Q1: if K must represent the total number of parameters to be estimated as per canonical definition of [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), why dividing it by the number of periods? This uncertainty seems to be shared in part by [this Stata guide](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/restatic.pdf) that, at page 3, says "K is the number of parameters estimated. Some authors define the AIC as the expression above divided by the sample size".

Q2: in a multivariate settings like this one (where I have a total number of variables in the vectors $y_{t}$ and $x_{t}$ equal to N for each $t$), if I use the BIC, shall I substitute the canonical penalization $ln(T)2*K$ with $ln(T*N)2*K$ in order to incorporate the fact that the total number of datapoints is T for each of the N time series (instead of just T as in the univariate case)?

Do you have any references on the AIC/BIC for a dynamic regression like this? Many thanks

P.S.: Even if it doesn't deal with ICs, I post here a useful link for everybody interested in a good source for the general formulation of the Expectation Maximization, including the cases of time-varying parameters and/or external regressors with/without constraints https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/EMDerivation.pdf

Comment: See also the formulation for VAR at pag 388 [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/varModels.pdf)

Comment: Alternative Akaike’s IC for State Space model, called AICi, is derived here http://myweb.uiowa.edu/cavaaugh/doc/pub/aici_ss.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the topic of Info Criteria for State Space Models is extensively reviewed [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/30b9/c80f827404a7aafe8fd335f13685e6397ce3.pdf). In particular, different Criteria are listed at pag. 480-481 , along with their comparative performances in simulated samples.

In R, the implementation is explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dse/vignettes/Guide.pdf) in the section relating to Information Tests at the bottom of pag. 13, and [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/rdrr.io/a/cran/MARSS/man/MARSSaic.html) .